# Django equivalent to SQL statement? Also, working with RawQuerySets?

Tags: sql, django

I'm running into the not-so-well-documented conundrum where you need to GROUP BY and ORDER BY at the same time.

EDIT to include some models:

```
class Matchup(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    opponent = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)

class Match(models.Model):
    game = models.CharField()
```

I think I've included everything important. I'm trying to make a leaderboard, where each player can only have one entry. Therefore I need to group_by Player, and order_by('-skill'). I messed around with distinct() for quite a while with no good results.

After hours of trial-and-error I've arrived at a 90% solution, by executing raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC) AS temp_table GROUP BY user ORDER BY score DESC
```

Admittedly I don't wholly understand the SQL (mainly, why is the 2nd ORDER BY necessary?)

1) Is this the best way? I could not return the proper result sets using the Django ORM, but it's very probable I was just doing a poor job.

2) I'd like to filter further by a foreignkey relation (match.game, want to have high scores per game). Best way when working with a rawqueryset?

Comment: Howdy! Perhaps you could start by explaining (with some sample data, even) what exactly you're trying to do? It's sometimes hard to guess just by looking at code.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I'm usually more thorough. I've edited to include some models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>On a side note first:  In your example, the **first** `ORDER BY` isn't necessary.  They never are in subselects, and in fact for a lesser RDBMS it would introduce an unnecessary ordering operation (I imagine most ignore this `ORDER BY` though).</s>  (**Edit**: Strictly speaking, this isn't true.  However, in most usages, the ordering of the tables doesn't matter and only the order of your resultset matters.  Your query actually is an interesting exception)

But what you're doing can be accomplished with the Django ORM and doesn't require raw SQL.  Your SQL is kind of weird in general.  Basically you can rewrite it as:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    scores
GROUP BY
    user
ORDER BY
    score DESC
```

The subselect isn't really doing anything (ordering isn't important for the source data, only in the output), so it just goes away.

So in this case, for the Django ORM part, you can just use [the aggregation features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation) to accomplish what you need.

**edit** - since you pointed out in the comments that the first `ORDER BY` actually does sort of have an effect due to the byproduct of using `SELECT *`[1] without any aggregations while `GROUP`ing, the relevant SQL would be:

```
SELECT
    user
    ,MAX(score) AS high_score
FROM
    scores
GROUP BY
    user
ORDER BY
    MAX(score) DESC
```

And again you can use the aggregation features mentioned at the link above to get the equivalent ORM statements.  It'd look something like this:

```
User.objects.annotate(high_score=Max('scores__score')).order_by('high_score')
```

This assumes you've got a foreign key from `Score` to `User` (Django will figure out how to join the two to get the related field `score` from your `Score` model).

[1] - This also highlights why it's not a good practice to use `SELECT *` in actual code!

Comment: Your SQL returns only the first-ever score a user has achieved. The GROUP BY takes only the first score. Then the scores are ordered by score, which renders the wrong result set (players can achieve many scores, and I only want their highest (actually current, but I'd accept highest)).

Comment: Aha, then you should be using `MAX()`.  Using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, `MAX`, etc.) tends to not make any sense, which is why I missed that.

Comment: Can Django manipulate the high_score without it being specified in the model?

Comment: @sejje yeah, using the `annotate` function from the link I'd been specifying - I've edited in an attempt at translating to the ORM syntax (it's untested)

Comment: Thanks danny boy! I'll give it a shot after I read up on this aggregation.